# Will a 0.5V difference in output damage the device?

Tags: ac, output, ratings

I have a speaker adapter, with an output rating of AC 11.5V ~ 1600mA, which I am looking to replace and the only replacement I can find has a rated output of 12V ~ 2000mA.

I've read somewhere that a higher current is okay since the speakers will only draw what it needs, but I'm wary if the 0.5 difference in voltage will overload/damage it.

Comment: Thank you, that was a very informative read. The only thing missing is how much of a deviation in output voltage can be considered "safe" to use.

Comment: It's hard to say how much more voltage is safe.  In this case, going from 11.5 to 12 is probably OK.

Comment: An AC power adapter is just a transformer, if your mains voltage is 220 V you might get 11.5 V but when it is 230 V you would get 12 V ! Your mains supply voltage is not that accurate so devices using a AC transformer must be able to withstand a higher voltage. I think a device rated for 11.5 V AC must be able to handle 12 V AC without any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of thing where it's just an unregulated AC transformer it's *probably* fine; I suspect if you had measured the original transformer it wouldn't be exactly 11.5V.

Although if it's a linear power supply it might put out slightly more heat than it used to, which may not be safe.